# How to Print Browser console logs using Cucumber Ruby Automation?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

Can you please help on printing the console logs generate in web browser for any errors in Cucumber Capybara Test Automation?
I am using PhantomJS webdriver as below:

> Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :phantomjs,
>   desired_capabilities: { 'phantomjs.cli.args' =>
>   ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes']

I want to capture Browser JS console logs and print it while i need on automation execution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you're using selenium you can try

```
page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get("browser")
```

Note: I've never tried it with PhantomJS as the browser

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have used below codes:                                logs = page.driver.manage.logs.get("browser");
    p "Logs: #{logs}"                             Getting below error: undefined method `manage' for #<Capybara::Selenium::Driver:0x007fa1574910b0> (NoMethodError)         Please help...

Comment: That's right. I don't know how to accept it. I will accept after it works. Anyway still not working. I am getting this error while using chrome.                 unknown error: log type 'chrome' not found
        (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError) . If the status is 200 instead any javascript errors, i should get 200 status code

Comment: Your question specifically says you're using PhantomJS -- where did using chrome come from?

Comment: Huh -- I'm not really sure what you're asking now -- What do status codes have to do with console logs?

Comment: but the log types arent chrome or phantomjs  - the logtype is "browser" -- .get("browser")